# Find in word from one file to another file using awk, NR==FNR

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to find words from one file to another file using following awk command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}($1 in a){print a[$2] " " $2}' file1 file2
```

content of files are :

file1:

> vidhu 1
>
> gangwar 2

file2:

> 1 1
>
> 2 4980022

Expected Output:

> vidhu 1
>
> gangwar 4980022

But output is coming like that :

> vidhu 1
>
> 4980022

Help me out to find this problem.

Comment: With `($1 in a){print a[$2]` you're testing if `$1` exists as an index in `a[]` but then trying to print the content of `a[]` indexed by a completely different value, `$2`. Think about that...

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you so much for pointing out this logical error. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$2]=$1;next} ($1 in A){print A[$1], $2}'  Input_file1   Input_file2
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk 'FNR==NR                   #### Checking condition of FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file1 is being read.
{A[$2]=$1;                     #### create an array named A with index of field  2 and have value as first field.
next}                          #### using next keyword(built-in awk) so it will skip all next statements.
($1 in A)                      #### Now checking if first field of file2 is present in array A, this will be checked only when Input_file2 is being read.
{print A[$1], $2               #### printing value of array A's value whose index is $1 and $2 of Input_file2.
}' Input_file1  Input_file2    #### Mentioning the Input_file1 and Input_file2 here.
```

Comment: `+1` but for clarity and to avoid clashes with builtin variables, never use all upper case variable names in awk or shell (except exported variables in shell).

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton for encouragement :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 file1 file2 -o 1.1,2.2
```

Assuming that your files are in sorted order.

If not then first sort them.